# how to generate codes for input excel table's field

Tags: python, excel

I have many columns in my excel table and I would like to generate code for my input to python.
My sentence is:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO router VALUES ('x','y','z')")
```

---

X,Y,Z are the parameters of 3 fields in my table.

As I can't find any method to generate sentence?
Will it work if I am using excel to generate sentence?
If yes, could u provide some info or answer to me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following data in 'csv' file:

```
x,y,z
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

Here's the example code to generate code strings:

```
>>> import pyexcel as pe
>>> records = pe.get_records(file_name='data.csv')
>>> records
[{'y': u'2', 'x': u'1', 'z': u'3'}, {'y': u'5', 'x': u'4', 'z': u'6'}]
>>> for record in records:
...     print("INSERT INTO router VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')" %(record['x'],record['y'], record['z']))
... 
INSERT INTO router VALUES ('1','2','3')
INSERT INTO router VALUES ('4','5','6')
```

If your data are in any of these formats: xls, xlsx, ods, please install corresponding plugins, for example, if you had xls:

```
pip install pyexcel-xls
```

then:

```
>>> import pyexcel as pe
>>> import pyexcel.ext.xls
>>> records = pe.get_records(file_name='data.xls')
```

The same principle applies to xlsx and ods. Here's the documentation to the [library](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)